# OSX Server: failed to connect to the IGD

Tags: macos, airport, server.app

Until recently I had an airport extreme as my router that I managed with Server.app for external NAT for server services in Mavericks/Server 3.1.1. However since I got a new router, server system log is filling up with the error below:

> servermgrd[2594]: Failed to connect to the IGD, no status info
>   available, error is Error Domain=com.apple.ACPDevice Code=-6753 "The
>   operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (com.apple.ACPDevice error
>   -6753.)"

Any idea how I can disable this feature so it doesn't keep trying to connect to the IGD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete :managedIGD" /Library/Server/Network/Config/autoportmap.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete :lastIGD" /Library/Server/Network/Config/autoportmap.plist
```

These commands are from 
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200038?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US which explains how to remove an Airport Base Station from Server in Mountain Lion. They also apply to Mavericks.